# Why is "I stayed playing videogames all night" wrong?

Tags: american-english

One of the definitions of the word **stay** is:

to continue doing something, or to continue to be in a particular state:

> stay open/closed The shops stay open until 9 o' clock.

I was talking to someone and I said **"I stayed playing videogames the whole night"** and the person said I was wrong. I should've said **"I played video games all night".** Why is "**I stayed playing" incorrect?

Answer (score 3):

The forms

> - I kept playing videogames the whole night.
> - I continued playing videogames the whole night.
> - I played videogames the whole night.

are all more common and more natural than "I stayed playing videogames the whole night." The word 'stayed" is more often used with something indicating **state** such as "stayed open" or "stayed angry", or with something indicating place or position, as "stayed at home" or "stayed out".

I can't say that "stayed playing" is a grammatical error, but it is not a natural usage in my opinion.

[This Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stayed+playing%2C+kept+playing%2C+continued+playing+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstayed%20playing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckept%20playing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccontinued%20playing%3B%2Cc0) shows "kept playing" as rather common, "continued playing" as a bit less common, and "stayed playing" as very close to **never** occurring in the underlying corpus.